# Redirect API path using htaccess rule to Slim Routes

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, slim

I have an API path like this

http://localhost/myProject/public/delivery/324

So Whenever I hit the API with {projectPath}/delivery Or {projectPath}/delivery/{id}, the API pinging the public/delivery/index.php as I write the RewriteRule in htaccess like

`RewriteRule ^delivery/(.*)$ delivery/index.php [QSA,NC,L]`

And my delivery/index.php contains the actual slim routes as below,

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\App(["settings" => $config]);


$app->group("/delivery", function(){
    $this->post("", "MyController:createDelivery");
    $this->get("/{id}", "MyController:getDeliveryId");
});
$app->run();
```

Control is coming to delivery/index.php. But, slim routes are not working and it is not pinging the `MyController`. Is anything I am missing here?

Comment: Then what happend if you remove the group? If you are redirecting from `.htaccess` to `deilvery/index.php` and that file contains slim initialization, then i think you can remove the delivery group from slim and work only with `/` and `/{id}` routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Pipe comment, I got this working as below,

```
$app->post("/", "MyController:createDelivery");
$app->get("/{id}", "MyController:getDeliveryId");
```